# Как загрузить аватары на сервер

Tags: php

Как загрузить аватары на сервер? Я уже получил на сервере $_FILES['name'], как его загрузить его в определенное место

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_FILES['name']))
{
  if(copy($_FILES['name']['tmp_name'],"../uploads/".$_FILES['name']['name'])) //тут папка и путь к ней куда грузим
  {
   else echo "загружено";
  }
  else echo "ошибка при загрузке файла";
}
```

Как-то так примерно. Подробнее нужно смотреть конкретный пример и делать варианты под него. Но без изучения мат части не обойтись. Потому что мало просто загрузить. Наверняка надо еще и проверить а картинки ли это. Потом с размерами не все так просто. Зачастую надо размеры менять.

Comment: Во-первых, уже первая строка вашего примера выдаст ошибку. Во-вторых, лучше использовать  **move_uploaded_file()** чем **copy()**.

Comment: Теперь не выведет.
Кавычки лишние влезли, при копировании названия из вопроса автора.